# How to encrypt and decrypt mvc urls along with controller and action name in mvc 5?

Tags: encryption, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to know if there is any way to encrypt and decrypt the mvc urls along with its controller and action names. Areas names should not be encrypted i.e the url should look like this : **http://domainName.com/MyAreaName?MyParam=encryption**

where **MyParam** is the parameter name that is being passed to the url or the page.
Please suggest me few complete sample links to get an idea.

Comment: Can you just use https?

Comment: Actually http or https dont matter, i dont want the user to see my controller and action names and the parameter value in the url, it should be kind of hashed.

Comment: If you hash the url, then ASP would not be able to work out what the client wants to do (what route you want). What you are asking makes no sense at all. Perhaps some context would help...but I doubt it.

Comment: My current url is :: MyDomain.com/Dashboards/MyDashboard/Page?Pageid=37, where area=Dashboards, controller =MyDashboard, action=Page, parameter=Pageid,parameter value=37. I would like to show the url to user like this : MyDomain.com/Dashboards/encryption?Pageid=encrypted.

Comment: Okay, perhaps I didn't make myself clear. WHAT PROBLEM does this solve? Because, I am trying to understand how you would navigate a website where the url is encrypted. You would also be breaking a basic promise of HTTP GET. Depending on what you are doing, you might even break bookmarking. You are breaking so many thing, but you haven't given me a single upside to what you are doing.

Comment: just hiding the url in terms of security concern. Also if i show the user parameter value 37, then user might tend to play by changing it to 38 or 40, which might be security issues, if he is not intended to see tht data

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215225/most-effective-method-of-protecting-an-entity-id-when-posting-back-from-a-view

Answer (score 1):

Okay. That is actually a serious, but solved issue. Encryption is NOT the key to the problem, at least not traditional security encryption. There are several properties of strong encryption that makes it impractical.

1. Performance (encryption is expensive)
2. Determinism (without determinism, you lose performance to caching)

UUID/GUID

The traditional method to avoid sequential ids is to use non-sequential ids. If you expose UUID/GUID on your website, would be hackers would not be able to figure out

1. How many customers you have from the largest id you have
2. How to access Bob's account by id.

UUIDs look like `de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546014` and you cannot increment it to find the next record.

Comment: Thanks for the details, but is there a way in mvc to encrypt the controller and action names even?

Comment: @goshan2011 What is the reason for the "action" name? Also, no, not transparently, since you need to also change your links.

Comment: @goshan2011 You said for "security" what is your threat model and attack vector?